# Asp.net core 6 / Scaffolding failed, Could not load information for project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I looked at several already existing questions but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

[image]

As you can see, I only have two projects : one web app MVC (.net 6) and one class librairy.
When i add a reference to my librairy in my web app, i cant create ANY "Scaffolding item".

Does anyone have a solution to this issue ?

Comment: Have you seen the following post: https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Fixed in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 6.0.10

Comment: After updating to Design 6.0.10 I was able to scaffold a controller including EF db context model. But I still get an error if I try to do a complete scaffold of controller and views in one step. After the controller is generated, I was able to generate a view by selecting an action and do Add View...